# Assembly Using Variables

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to make the text screen print 'h' which is stored in a variable. I am using NASM. x86 Protected Mode, a from scratch kernel.

```
DisplayMessage:
        ;mov byte[Color], 0xF
        ;mov CFC, EAX;
        ;mov byte[Color], 104
        ;push 104
        ;mov byte[esi], Msg
        ;lodsb
        mov ebx, Msg
        add ebx, 4
        mov [Msg], eax
        mov byte[0xB8000], Msg
        ;mov byte[eax], Color
        ;pop byte[0xB8000]
        ;mov byte[0xB8000], byte Color
        ;mov byte[0xB8000], 0xB500000;
        ;Now return
        ret
EndCode:
Msg: db 104
```

The letter it displays is never right. Whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: Mine. Its x86 Protected mode, from scratch.

Comment: so we have to assume that your OS has the text video page mapped to address 0xB8000? And we have to assume that the video card is in text mode?

Comment: what's the point of including all the commented out code? it just makes it harder to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It was just code that doesn't work. Just left it there for reference. I will remove it once I get this working. =)

Answer (score 9):

```
    mov ebx, Msg ; this loads ebx with the address of Msg, OK
    add ebx, 4 ; this increments the address by 4, OK, but why?
    mov [Msg], eax ; this stores eax into the first 4 bytes of Msg, OK, but why?
    mov byte[0xB8000], Msg ; this writes the least significant byte of the
                           ; address of Msg to the screen, not OK.
                           ; Does not make any sense.
```

Why not just?:

```
mov al, [Msg]
mov [0xB8000], al
```

This should write the very first character of `Msg` ('h' has ASCII code 104, correct) at the top-left corner of the screen, if, of course, your data segment has the base address of 0 in its segment descriptor, and if your `org` is correct.

Comment: What about VGA text mode color codes? I think that's what the `+4` is for.

Comment: @Linuxios In color text modes, every character cell on the screen is defined by 2 (two) bytes, the first being the character code and the second, a combination of background and foreground colors. Where does 4 come from in here?

Comment: Ok so the +4, ignore that was me testing something. But I tried the
<pre>
mov al, [Msg]
mov [0xB8000], al
</pre>

And, it displayed nothing. However, I think I didn't set the base address or the segment descriptor, and I don't know what the org is 'org 0x200000'. How do I set the other two? Maybe that's the problem. And why did you use the 'al' register? Thanks - Matt

Comment: @civilwarrock: `<pre>` doesn't work here. Use the backquote (```)(that's 3 of them) to delimitate code in text.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Oh wait... It was incrementing the address. Sorry!

Comment: @Linuxios Ok. I can't edit my comment, but I will keep that in mind. Now I am not rolling my own bootloader. I'm using syslinux. Just thought I would say that. =)

Comment: @civilwarrock: Good for you. Rolling your own bootloader (I'm trying to do this too right now) is a pain, and really not worth your time with so many good ones like GRUB and SYSLINUX.

Comment: @Linuxios Exactly. But I just don't understand why I can't print 'h' when its in a variable. Cause like i can pass 104 to the memory location, I see a 'h'. But when I try to pass even a 1 byte value variable instead, it either is some weird letter. Or nothing. And like once when I get a letter to print, even though it wasn't 104, if I changed the variables value it was still the same letter. Its like its using the location of where the variable is stored or something... Just would like to get working with variables working. I even tried 'lodsb' which didn't do the job either. =(

Comment: You have some problems with how you set up segments and compile code to us them. Some things don't match. I can't tell where the bugs are without seeing the code.

Comment: @civilwarrock: You just need to make sure that the defined value is one byte, and that you use a 1 byte register to hold it.

Comment: Ok here's the defined variable right now: 'Msg: db 104' is that right? One byte that equals 104, which in ASCII is 'h'. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

VGA text mode uses address `0xB8000` as an array of `uint16_t` With the upper byte being used for color, and the lower byte being the character code. Currently you are storing the character in the upper byte and the lower byte is untouched. It may be random noise that is printing a random character. Try this:

```
DisplayMessage:
mov al, byte [msg]
mov ah, 0x0F ;White Text on Black Background
mov word [0xB8000], ax
ret
```